# Is Python's struct.Struct object thread-safe?

Tags: python, struct, thread-safety, python-multithreading, pack

In Python, there is a [`struct.Struct`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/struct.html#struct.Struct) class for efficiently packing and unpacking data, instead of calling `struct.pack` all the time. I want to know if it is safe for threads to share the same `Struct` object. The documentation has no mention of thread-safety, and there is also this confusing note:

> **Note:** The compiled versions of the most recent format strings passed to `Struct` and the module-level functions are cached, so programs that use only a few format strings needn’t worry about reusing a single Struct instance.

Comment: It should be safe. As far as I know, none of the methods (`Struct.pack`, `Struct.unpack`, etc) require any sort of mutable shared state to do their job. Aside from the `size` descriptor, there's little difference between `Struct(fmt_string)` and a collection of partially applied functions like `partial(struct.pack, fmt_string)`.

Comment: @chepner do you have a source? I would like to be sure about this!

Comment: No source, but if I discovered that `Struct` objects *weren't* thread-safe, I would report it as a bug. There's really no reason for them *not* to be thread-safe.

Comment: For example, given `s = Struct.("!I")`, you can't modify either `s.format` or `s.size`; they are read-only attributes.

Comment: Ok, I looked in the CPython source and can see no variables storing temporary state etc. (https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c4cacc8c5eab50db8da3140353596f38a01115ca/Modules/_struct.c#L39)

Comment: Keep in mind that other implementations will have ... well, other implementations of the `struct` module, but like I said, there's no reason why it *shouldn't* be thread-safe.

Answer (score 0):

## Yes

There are no temporary state variables used in a Struct, and all its attributes (`format` and `size`...) are read-only so there is no reason why you can't use it across threads.